# Trouble Embedding Facebook Posts

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to get my fb posts to directly display on my website. It works if I use the link but I want it to embed directly on my site. I put in exactly what they told me to... Any thoughts?

```
    <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '739994246046761',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=739994246046761&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/binghamtoncrushes" data-width="600" data-height="250" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Comment: why have you got 2 calls to their JS SDK?

Comment: not really sure.. just doing what they said to do..

Comment: Well you only need one : ) remove everything after `<div id="fb-root"></div>` up until `<div class="fb-like-box" ....` and try again. Post and console errors if you're getting any.

Comment: you could also remove all the code above the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` either options *should* work

Comment: the error that comes up is ... 'GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ' the same error is there with that script. it says the error is on the line.. '  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);'

Comment: Well that file definitely does exist and after removing the duplicate call to the SDK there's no reason it shouldn't work. Do you have a test page url that you could post?

Comment: i saw another overflow post and they said to add http: to that line above and now there are no errors. its just not showing up. now the console says 'XHR finished loading: GET "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/likebox/stream?id=327790060684188&dom…ser=602260892&__a=1&__dyn=7wfGbwKBWo2vw&__req=1&locale=en_US&__rev=1358170". ' but nothing is displayed in the browser

Comment: and it says 'fb:like_box failed to resize in 45s '

Comment: For me testing by removing the code before the `fb-root` div it works and shows up correctly. Something else might be conflicting with this on your page. If you try it on a stand alone page does it work?

Comment: it is on a standalone page and does not work. could it be bc im running it locally?

Comment: potentially, I've not got a local environment set up right now to test that myself

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) 
 {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
   js = d.createElement(s); 
   js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
 }
 (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152504396908837" data-width="466">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152504396908837">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HuffPostSports">HuffPost Sports</a>.</div>
</div>
```